# Where does the control return after calling a function within a

Tags: c++

```
class x{
public:
 int A(){
    B();//function call
    }
int B(){
   //print stuff
  }
```

so i am trying to figure out after B() is called where does the control returns after that this program is showing "Compile time exceeds" and if put return after printing would controol go back to the A() or main();

Comment: Control always goes back to where you called the function from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control will return back to the **A()** function since the **B()** is having int return type it will return with a Int value.

```
class x{
public:
int A(){
   val = B();//function call
 //If B() was initialised in a variable value of
 // Val will become the return value of B()
}
int B(){
   //print stuff
 // After Print it will go back to A()
}
```

Even if B() don't have int return type and you don't put a **return** in B() the program control will always go back to the **calling function** after executing all the statements of **B()**

if **B()** is having **void**, the control will always flow back to the calling function

Comment: What if B() has void?

Comment: @GauravBhardwaj if B() is having void, the control will always flow back to the calling function.